# Can't change color of individual segments of EPS in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I have the image above as an EPS file. What I want to do is apply color to the segments with different colors. I'm in Illustrator and have never run across this issue with an EPS file. So far I've tried the following:

- I can't even count the number of times I've selected the image and
  hit `Ungroup`, but that hasn't helped.
- When I double-click on a
  segment with the Selection Tool, Illustrator takes me into something
  called Isolation Mode. It allows me to select individual sections and
  move, delete, or otherwise manipulate just that segment, but not to
  apply a different color to it.
- When I click on a segment with the Direct Selection Tool, it automatically selects all of the segments in the image. It won't let me isolate an individual segment.
- I've also tried to `copy` and `paste`
  segments and apply the color to the copy, but that doesn't work.

Everything I've tried so far has failed. With each, whenever I try to apply color to an individual segment, Illustrator applies the color to the whole image.

Any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Try releasing the clipping mask that's forming the actual shape?

Comment: I don't have that option. But it has a sub-layer, called "Compound Path," and when I release that, the color extends over the whole image and a bunch of additional sub-layers appear in the Layers window, each for a different segment. I'm not enough of an expert at Illustrator to know what's going on.

Comment: Ah so its just a compound path--- in that case just select the individual paths with the group selection tool (select so you have the outer edge and its inner edge selected. then cut and paste in front it, usinc ctrl+x +ctrl+f)

Comment: Thanks! The only way that works is if I paste it to a new layer, which I've done.